# Polymer 0.4 JSONP

Tags: jsonp, polymer, web-component

I'm playing around with Polymer 0.4. I'm trying to do a jsonp request using polymer-jsonp component which I've installed using bower.

But it's not working, it looks to me like the polymer-jsonp component is not compatible with Polymer 0.4 and it has been deprecated according to this https://github.com/PolymerLabs/polymer-jsonp/releases/tag/0.3.0

I can see in my network panel that the polymer-jsonp comoponent is being correctly imported but even though it has the "auto" parameter it does not make the request at all. I'm not running it throug any JS code, I'm expecting it to run automatically because of the auto param and to bind it results to the results param value.

May I wait for a compatible version to be released or is there any way to use it or some alternative?

EDIT:
Here is an example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>Polymer WebApp</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
  <!-- Place favicon.ico and apple-touch-icon.png in the root directory -->

  <!-- build:css styles/main.css -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css">
  <!-- endbuild-->

  <script src="bower_components/platform/platform.js"></script>
  <!-- build:vulcanized elements/elements.vulcanized.html -->
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-drawer-panel/core-drawer-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer-jsonp/polymer-jsonp.html">
  <link rel="import" href="elements/elements.html">
  <!-- endbuild-->
  <style>
    #drawer {
      background-color: #CCC;
    }
    #main {
      background-color: #EBFA6F;
    }
    #main site-table {
      padding: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body unresolved>
  <template>
    <polymer-jsonp url="http://127.0.0.1/abmonitor-server/Ajax.class.php?callback=" auto response="{{ sitelist }}"></polymer-jsonp>
  </template>
  <core-drawer-panel>
    <div id="drawer" drawer>
      <sites-menu></sites-menu>
    </div>
    <div id="main" main>
      <header>
        <core-toolbar>Toolbar</core-toolbar>
      </header>
      <site-table></site-table>
    </div>
  </core-drawer-panel>
  <!-- build:js scripts/app.js -->
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
  <!-- endbuild-->
</body>

</html>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The jsonp element really should be updated for core, it's just a nuisance that is hasn't been yet. However, I looked at the code, and I believe the old one should work just fine. It's possible you just have a simple problem in your setup.

> I can see in the browser console that it is not being imported.

Make sure you have a `<link>` tag in your application that imports the element. Probably something like:

```
<link rel="import" href="bower_components/polymer-jsonp/polymer-jsonp.html>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. The import is right and it's actually loading but not excecuting the request even though it has the "auto" parameter. I'll edit my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is your best chance at getting a solution.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I don't have much time right now but I'll add a mvce as soon as I can. Thank you @Scott Miles.